# Getting some error while performing map/reduce on pyspark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am just trying to learn  the PySpark, but confused about the difference between the following two RDDs, I know one is type set and one is list but both are RDDs

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 3)])
type(rdd)
```

and

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['a, 1', 'b, 1', 'a, 3'])
type(rdd)
```

Code for processing map and reduce functions:

```
priceMap= s.map(lambda o: (o.split(",")[0], float(o.split(",")[1])))
priceMap.reduceByKey(add).take(10)
```

I can easily perform the map/reduce function on the second rdd data, but when I try to perform the map or reduce I get the following error: so how can we convert the first rdd to second rdd data, or if there is any way to resolve the following error please help. thanks

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 162.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.0 in stage 162.0 (TID 3850, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):

Comment: The traceback suggests there is a python exception. Please show your map/reduce code - the error probably stems from there

Comment: @mck yes, I updated the two lines of code for the map and reduce, could you please help me there. Thanks

Comment: s and add are undefined variables

Comment: put rdd name instead of s so it will be rdd.map(.... and add is the function, which you can import, following is the library, please import it......
from operator import add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first rdd, you can replace the map function:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 3)])
rdd.map(lambda o: (o[0], float(o[1]))).reduceByKey(add).collect()
```

That's because `split` only works with the strings but not tuples.

Comment: I tried that, did not work for me, I will try your code any will see if that works